# regex search and group

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i want to use regular expression and search "MsRtcOAuth href=\" and fetch the value of "https://google.com\"

```
STRING= "Bearer trusted_issuers=\"\", client_id=\"00000004-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000\", MsRtcOAuth href=\"https://google.com\",grant_type=\"urn:microsoft.rtc:windows,urn:microsoft.rtc:anonmeeting,password\""
```

Please tell me how to do it in JavaScript. I have done this in Python using re. Example:

```
m=re.search('MsRtcOAuth href="(.*?)"', STRING)
```

and get the result

```
m.group(1)="https://google.com\"
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Your regex will still capture the value in the first capturing group. Can you share the code that you have tried?

Comment: @Amit Singh Please don't forget to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you find it helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like as follows:

```js
const str = 'STRING= "Bearer trusted_issuers=\"\", client_id=\"00000004-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000\", MsRtcOAuth href=\"https://google.com\",grant_type=\"urn:microsoft.rtc:windows,urn:microsoft.rtc:anonmeeting,password\""';

console.log(str.match(/MsRtcOAuth href=\"(.*?)"/)[1]);
```